# OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long

Tags: python

I have a short script that needs to merge multiple MKV files into one every night.

```
import os, glob
import subprocess

concatenated_files = ""

os.chdir("/cams/")
for index, file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.mkv")):
    if index == 0:
        concatenated_files = file
    else:
        concatenated_files += " + " + file

# print(concatenated_files)

returncode = subprocess.call("mkvmerge -o out.mkv " + concatenated_files)
```

I am getting the following error with just a few files

```
OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long: 'mkvmerge -o out.mkv video21-06-28_09-12-08-51.mkv + video21-06-28_07-55-36-80.mkv + video21-06-28_09-52-05-79.mkv + video21-06-28_08-47-56-69.mkv + video21-06-28_09-15-04-34.mkv + video21-06-28_09-32-43-25.mkv
```

I am planning to merge hundreds of them, so not really sure how to sort this situation with Python. It works well from the shell.

Comment: `concatenated_files += " + " + file` -> `concatenated_files += " " + file`?

Comment: I need to get a + symbol in-between files @TuanChau

Comment: @voronoy: Does `subprocess.call("mkvmerge -o out.mkv " + concatenated_files, shell=True)` work ?

Comment: what happens when your run `mkvmerge -o out.mkv video21-06-28_09-12-08-51.mkv + video21-06-28_07-55-36-80.mkv + video21-06-28_09-52-05-79.mkv + video21-06-28_08-47-56-69.mkv + video21-06-28_09-15-04-34.mkv + video21-06-28_09-32-43-25.mkv` within your terminal? does it runs succesfully?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer It does indeed! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

subprocess.call() first argument "args" is a *list*.

So I think it should probably be like this:

```
  import os, glob
  import subprocess

  concatenated_files = ""

  os.chdir("/cams/")
  args = ["mkvmerge"]
  for index, file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.mkv")):
     args.append(file)


  args.append("-o")        
  args.append("out.mkv")        


  returncode = subprocess.call(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a shell script with only three lines of code is more simple and more clear:

```sh
ls /cams/ | grep -E ".+\.mkv$" | while read filename; do
  filenames="${filenames} ${filename}"
done
mkvmerge -o out.mkv ${filenames}
```

Comment: That's what I am currently moving away from given that when the file list is too long, it doesn't process it.

Comment: what means the file list is too long, there it does `grep -E ".+\.mkv$"` files what you want to merge, as the python script `glob.glob("*.mkv")` does.

Comment: It is ok to use the python script for merging if you solved your problem, this is just a choice.